# Questions on cassandra paging mechanism and cluster usage regulation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've got three questions on paging mechanics and cluster usage regulation.

1) Am I correct to assume that the larger page size some user session has set - the larger portion of cluster/coordinator node resources will be hogged by the corresponding session?

2) Do I understand correctly that page size (imagine we have no timeout settings) is limited by RAM and iops which I want to hand down to a single user session?

3) Am I correct to assume that the page size/read request timeout allowance I set is direct representation of chance to lock some node to single user's requests?